# Elegant way to combine a removeCartItem and addCartItem function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I feel like there much be a way to nest these functions together so that the code is more elegantly written but I'm not sure how. Everything works fine as is but it's two large functions nearly doing the same thing.

```
const addCartItem = (cartItems, productToModify) => {
  const existingCartItem = cartItems.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === productToModify.id);

  if (existingCartItem) {
    return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
      cartItem.id === productToModify.id ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 } : cartItem
    );
  }
  return [...cartItems, { ...productToModify, quantity: 1 }];
};

const removeCartItem = (cartItems, productToModify) => {
  const existingCartItem = cartItems.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === productToModify.id);

  if (existingCartItem) {
    return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
      cartItem.id === productToModify.id && cartItem.quantity > 0
        ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity - 1 }
        : cartItem
    );
  }
  return [...cartItems, { ...productToModify, quantity: 1 }];
};

const addItemToCart = (productToModify) => {
    setCartItems(addCartItem(cartItems, productToModify));
  };

  const removeItemFromCart = (productToModify) => {
    setCartItems(removeCartItem(cartItems, productToModify));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the differing parts into their own function, and pass it to a generic function containing the common parts:

```
const executeCartOperation = (cartItems, productToModify, cartOperation) => {
  const existingCartItem = cartItems.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === productToModify.id);

  if (existingCartItem) {
    return cartOperation(cartItems, productToModify);
  }
  return [...cartItems, { ...productToModify, quantity: 1 }];
};
```

And the different operations:

```
const addCartItem = (cartItems, productToModify) => {
  return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
      cartItem.id === productToModify.id && cartItem.quantity > 0
        ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity - 1 }
        : cartItem
    );
}



const removeCartItem = (cartItems, productToModify) => {
      return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
          cartItem.id === productToModify.id && cartItem.quantity > 0
            ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity - 1 }
            : cartItem
        );
    }
```